# jQuery 1.3 breaks with 1.4 script

Tags: jquery

I'm using a navigation drop down that uses jQuery 1.3 
http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/examples/mega-dropdowns/#

I'm also using the jQuery countdown script which is 1.4 similar to this script http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html

When I do this my drop down is broken.

How can I have my drop down and count it too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `jQuery.noConflict` you can have multiple versions of jQuery on one page

```
<script src='jquery-1.3.js'></script>
<script>
var jq13 = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
<script src='jquery-1.4.js'></script>
```

Then you'd have to change the usage of `$` in the  navigation drop down script to be `jq13`.